# Angular 1.5: Self enclosing component stops the page from continue rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `Angular@1.5.0-beta.2` and I used a tutorial to start using `component` function:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CountCtrl', function CountCtrl() {
    this.count = 10;
  })
  .component('counter', {
      bindings: {
      count: '='
    },
    controller: function TestCtrl() {
      TestCtrl.prototype.increment = function() {
        this.count += 1;
      };
      TestCtrl.prototype.decrement = function() {
        this.count -= 1;
      }
    },
    template:
      ['<div class="todo">',
      '<input type="text" ng-model="counter.count">',
      '<button type="button" ng-click="counter.decrement();">-</button>',
      '<button type="button" ng-click="counter.increment();">+</button>',
    '</div>'
  ].join('')
})
;
```

My html is:

```
<body ng-controller="CountCtrl as vm">
    <counter count="vm.count"/>
    <counter count="10"/>
  </body>
```

But only the first `counter` element is being rendered until I'm closing it like this`<counter></counter>`.

What seem to be the problem and is there any way working around this?

Comment: Aged of 2 years but maybe still valid : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953
Apparently you should not use self-enclosing tags...

Comment: Wow. That is news to me. Thanks.

Comment: Also in here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1237